# realm results not displayed on activity change

Tags: android, realm

I have stored values in `realmObject` using AsyncTask on `activity1` now on `activity2` I want to show the stored values fetch from same realm object, it sometimes displays the value and sometimes `RealmResults` are empty.

Is it `realm` results are not saved and I query it before. How can I resolve this issue?

Edit:

Activity 1:

In activity 1 Click on save button calls AsyncSaveCarList(AsyncTask) in which I store value in RealmObject.

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            Car carRealmObject = realm.createObject(Car .class);
                            carRealmObject .setCarID(jsonobject.getInt("CarID"));
                            carRealmObject .setName(jsonobject.getString("Name"));
  realm.commitTransaction();
```

Activity 2:

```
 RealmResults<Car> carRealmResult = realm.where(Car.class).findAll();
```

carRealmResult is sometimes filled and sometimes it is empty.

Comment: Show the part of code where you are storing and fetching

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: try doing this: `Car carRealmObject = new Car(); carRealmObject.setCarID(jsonobject.getInt("CarID")); carRealmObject.setName(jsonobject.getString("Name"));  realm.copyToRealm(carRealmObject); realm.commintTransaction()`

Comment: I don't think you need AsyncTask to save a single object, even if you need you should use [Asynchronous Transactions](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions) and in the success callback log out something and check whether the object is saved or not. Also may be you are querying the realm for the data before it is even saved.

Comment: Async Task is for calling the web API method and storing the value in Realm Object. Yes may be I'm querying the realm for the data before it is even saved, could you suggest how I should stop activity 2 to load before realm is saved or even activity 2 is loaded how should I display the result without page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mapping your RealmResults to arrays/arraylists, you should be using `RealmResults` directly and send them to your `RealmBaseAdapter`.

You shouldn't be using `ArrayList`+`ArrayAdapter` if you expect Realm to automatically update the UI when you write into it...

Comment: it gets worst if I do realm.refresh(). What should I do kindly let me know

Comment: I'm thinking to use SQL-lite just bcs of this issue. The car example is just a sample example I gave. This is the issue everywhere in my app and App is supposed to be used by thousands of users.

Comment: It can't possibly get "worse" with `realm.refresh()` used in `onPostExecute()`, because `realm.refresh()` forces the Realm to be at the latest version. It is impossible that you cannot find newly inserted values after `realm.refresh()` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: ....ah, by the way, if you don't see the new cars in the **async task**, then that means you are not closing the Realm on the background thread. Consider using `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())`.

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce issue is resolved using the suggested approach.